# what method is executed instread of __repr__ in jupyter notebook cells?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, ipython, repr

I have a data frame, say `df`, and when I go with `print(df)` or `repr(df)`, I get a not very palatable output.

`print(df)` result:

[image]

but when I just put a naked `df` in the cell and run it, I get something like this:

[image]

Question: Which function was implicitly executed to produce that output? I would like to put it in a for loop and display many dataframes that way.

Comment: What does `print(repr(df))` show?

Comment: @DerekO Yep! turns out to be `display` and its defined by `IPython`

Comment: @hpaulj it returns the same thing as `print` or `repr` alone. Turns out the the function I'm looking for is `display` defined by `IPython
`

Comment: @AlexDeft cool, i was pretty sure i had seen this answered before, and i'm glad that answer worked for you :)